# Why can I see through a box in blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine, normals

I have a problem where I can see through a box in blender game, see picture. This effect changes so that the near side of the "chassis" of the truck is invisible when I rotate the model

[image]

What can I do to not make this happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The normal (1) of the invisible face points in the wrong direction you can fix that by selecting the face and <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot]

You can verfiy this by displaying the normals (2)

Alternatively you could disable Backface Culling in the material's Game Settings (3).

Comment: You can also select all of the faces and "flip normals" (W then F). Or select the object and "Recalculate Outside" (Ctrl N).

Answer (score 7):

I think something wrong with face normals, you could check it this way:

[image: Normals]

Usually these lines should be at outer side of object volume. Track body shouldn't be considered as just box without top, it is very thin object with surfaces directed to "inside" and "outside".

Answer (score 1):

Try setting its Material's Alpha Blend to Alpha Clip, that usually helps.

[image: *PROPERTIES, MATERIALS TAB, GAME SETTINGS, ALPHA BLEND]